# Scala / Java word2vec reader

Tags: java, scala, word2vec

I've got several word2vec text files with the following standard layout:

```
numWords vecSize
word1 vec1 vec2 ...
word2 vec1 vec2 ...
...
```

Is there any Scala or Java library to read these and calculate simple stuff like:

- isWordInVocab
- getWordVectors
- nearestNeighbours
- cosDistance
- ...

I could find some only for binary formats, is there a way to use these (apart from writing my own one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just ended up writing my own class to avoid the whole dl4j/nd4j import/setup/run procedure.